# jchart2d for displaying dynamic charts with fast updating data

Tags: java, swing, real-time, charts

I want to use jcharts2d to plot fast updating data.

The examples for dynamic charts in their webpage use a dummy random function to simulate fast changing data, any ideas on how to feed data into the chart?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to supply a class that extends [ADataCollector](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc-v2/info/monitorenter/gui/chart/io/ADataCollector.html) and implements [collectData](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc-v2/info/monitorenter/gui/chart/io/ADataCollector.html#collectData%28%29)